Save intermediate price of realtime candle in var
I want to write the candle price in a var for every true of my indicator. I also want to output every candle price that was achieved by the indicator over the day in a total. Therefore, I want to summarize all profits that were made using the indicator over a session day in a total. Since I work with realtime candles, I don't want to have the close, open, high or low price because if I specify var myprice = close for realtime candles, I won't see the current price when the indicator = true, but the last close price of the entire realtime candle. It would be important for me to save the realtime price for the indicator true in a var, which is available when the indicator goes to true
Is there a Pinescript solution for this problem?
I tried this solution but it doesn't work here either:
varip myprice := ta.valuewhen(myindcator == true, close,0)

This can be done using varip, you initialize the variable as na, and then at each tick you check whether the condition of your indicator is met and the variable doesn't has a value, if it is true, then assign a new value, if not true, just leave the old value. Then on each new bar on first update before checking your condition drop the variable to na state
Example:
//@version=5
indicator("My scipt")
myCond = close > open and barstate.isrealtime
varip myPrice = float (na)
if not na(myPrice[1]) and barstate.isnew
    myPrice := na
myPrice := myCond and na(myPrice) ? close : myPrice
plot(myPrice)


Thanks for the info. The problem is that if the indicator is true from the first time until the candle is finished, then the close is written into the var again until the end of the candle and as a result I then have the last close of the candle in the var. How can I only write the first close into the var once when the indicator is true for the first time?


How can I only write the first close into the var once when the indicator is true for the first time?
Only once per whole indicator calculation or per one candle?


I only want the value once per real-time candle. Only when the indicator is true for the first time. I just don't know how I can query a price for a real-time candle only once when the indicator is true for the first time. One idea would be a counter that is incremented per real-time candle interval and only the first count can happen via an if query

Update the answer and the code, check it please

I tested the script. Unfortunately, this test again shows that the price of the indicator only shows the closing close. Here is the script that I used.
varip myPrice = float (na)
if not na(myPrice[1]) and barstate.isnew
myPrice := na
myPrice := ind_2_long == true and na(myPrice) ? close : myPrice
if not na(myPrice)
label.new(bar_index, na, ""+ str.tostring(myPrice), color=#86f377, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar, size = size.normal)
